# Executing a Java application with sockets & jdbc from PHP

Tags: java, mysql, sockets, jdbc, sudo

I cannot get a Java application to run correctly when starting it with sudo.  My application uses sockets for client connections and also establishes a database connection.  If I start the app normally:

```
java myApp
```

Everything works perfectly.  However, I am trying to get this to be able to be started in the background from a website.  So I created a PHP to start it using exec() or passthru().  At first, this seemed to work, but I soon discovered the sockets weren't actually connecting.  Further trial and error led me to the conclusion this was because when I do `java myApp`, I am logged in as root, but the PHP is not executing as root so there's security issues.

So I wrote a script, set SUDOERS to allow the script to be run without a password.  The script has a single line, `java myApp`.  If I run the script with:

```
bash myScript
```

The sockets won't connect.  (Which is to say the applet client hangs trying to connect.)  If I try:

```
sudo bash myScript
```

The jdbc MySql driver fails to be found.  I tried various methods to cure this, including messing with the classpath including using -classpath at compile and / or runtime and putting a copy of the jdbc jar in different places but no luck.  Apparently, the sudo environment is different in some subtle way from the logged-in-as-root environment which causes Java to not be able to find the jdbc drivers.

To be clear, I get the jdbc ClassPathNotFound (or no suitable driver error, depending on how I attempt the connection) when I try to run `sudo bash myScript` while logged in as root.  `bash myScript` works just fine on all counts logged in as root.  When I try to run the the either from a PHP script, my client applet can't connect, which could either be the sockets or jdbc.  I am not using an IDE of any sort, just editing with text editors and using javac to compile.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Update:

The server is running CentOS, if that helps.  I figured the -E was an environment thing (and had guessed environment loss was the cause, but the sudo documentation I was finding wasn't helping me figure out the solution).  I have tried `passthru('sudo -i bash /path/to/myScript.sh');` but the java app still fails to start.  Nothing shows up in the browser from the passthru.  The script now reads:

```
cd /path/to/app
java myApp
```

Still toying with it myself; I know I am close to making this work.

Comment: Does your script set the classpath to tell the Java app where the database drivers are?

Comment: @EugenRieck:  That helped.  Running the script directly works great with `sudo -E bash myScript`, but from the PHP script something is failing.

@Mano:  I have tried every variation I can think of for specifying the classpath.

Comment: To be more specific, the exec or passthru (I have tried both) are not launching the script.  Nothing appears to be happening.  The PHP is:
<?php
passthru("sudo -E bash myScript.sh");
?>

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion via the comments I understand, that `sudo -E` works (for your username) - this seems to be the giveaway to what goes on:

Your interactive logon has lots of environment variables set up, some of which are needed for execution of Java apps.

Normally, `sudo` will "clean up" your environment before switching user - so it will remove the necessary environment variables, but `sudo -E` will keep the environment intact, making it work for you.

Now the webserver user (e.g. www-data in Ubuntu) has no environment set up, making `sudo -E` keep a defective environment.

There are a few ways to address that, the easiest being to use `sudo -i` - this will run the target user's shell as if on login.

Comment: This was helpful, although I am still not getting the java app started.  See my update to the question.

Comment: We need to dig deeper - try this for a starter: In your normal environment (app working) `set >  /path/to/starterscript.sh && echo "cd /path/to/app" >> /path/to/starterscript.sh && echo "java myApp" >> /path/to/starterscript.sh`. Then `sudo -u wwwrun /bin/bash` (or whatever the apache user is called) and finally `sudo /path/to/starterscript.sh` and see if the app comes up.

Comment: How do I find what the apache user is?

Comment: Sorry, not a Redhat guy: Quick & dirty is run `ps auxwww | grep apache` and look for the username.

Comment: The apache username appears to be:  apache.  When I tried this, I got lots of new stuff in the script file.  I followed the next steps, and got prompted for the root password, which I am trying to avoid.  /etc/sudoers has this line:  `www ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash path/to/script/script.sh` So why is it prompting for the password?

Comment: If the user is `apache` (not `www`) you need `apache  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash path/to/script/script.sh` - maybe that is all that was wrong with the `sudo -i` version? sudo would wait for the password from PHP (which never comes), resulting in exactly nothing happening - just as you observed

Comment: ... gone for an hour, evening walk with the dog

Comment: I double checked and found the password I am being prompted for is the apache password, not the root password.  I have to wonder if that's the prompt that's stopping me.

Comment: To be specific, that's the prompt I got earlier when I did the sudo apache /bin/bash followed by sudo script.  Is that a quirk of doing it from my root environment?

Comment: If you get a PW prompt for `sudo -u apache /bin/bash` forget it, this doesn't happen, when you run from PHP. if you get a PW prompt for `sudo /path/to/starterscript.sh`check your sudo settings

Comment: After some experimentation, I have become convinced that the server is prompting for a password for user Apache.  I logged in as a different user, set SUDOERS to allow that user access to `sudo /bin/bash` with no password prompt, then tried `sudo -i -u root /path/to/myScript.sh` (I know the -u root should be superfluous) and got prompted for the user's password before it would run the script.  So now I am trying to find a way for the system to not prompt for a specific user's password.

Comment: If you run `sudo -i [-u root] /path/to/myScript.sh` you need to have `/path/to/myScript.sh` in your `sudoers` - if you have `/bin/bash` there, you need to run `sudo -i [-u root] /bin/bash /path/to/myScript.sh`, which should do the same thing

Comment: I *finally* figured it out.  Got input from STDERR, and from that found I needed to comment out `Default requiretty` in sudoers.

Comment: Congrats! So it was `sudo -i` + no `requiretty` ?